# How to add login credential via python script?

Tags: python, authentication, curl, python-requests, authorization

I am sure this is an answered question somewhere, but I could not find a solution for me (if you know a duplicate feel free to mark it).

My goal is to query a RESTful API. To do that I need to authenticate. The only way available for me for this API is via web-browser.

Basically, I am loading URL which redirects to another URL. In the second URL, there is a form where I need to input `username` and `password` to authenticate. Currently, I input the credentials manually via a web browser.

My question is: Can I do this programmatically such that I don't have to manually input the credentials via a web browser?

Note: the webpage is not verified.

**Attempt 1**

I tried the following commands, but none worked:

```
curl -k -u username:password https://myurl:port
```

It did not return anything.

**Attempt 2**

```
BASE_URL = 'https://myurl:port'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
r = requests.get(BASE_URL, auth=(username, password), verify=False)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

it prints `<Response [200]>` but it does not authenticate. This is because when I try to query an API endpoint - it says I am unauthorized. When I input the credentials manually in the browser - then the endpoint query works.

**Attempt 3**

Finally, I thought (but did not do) I need some way to read the login page and input credentials by getting the html elements and then clicking log in (with selenium for example), but this seems too rough and error-prone. Maybe there is a more elegant way.

Any ideas of how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, I am loading URL which redirects to another URL. In the
>   second URL, there is a form where I need to input username and
>   password to authenticate

From your description it sounds like you are accessing an API using OAuth2 with the *authorization code grant* flow ?...which by design requires the user (=resource owner) to authorise (via the form) your app (=client) to access his/her data provided by the API (=resource server). in this case, using basic auth (Attempt 1 and 2) will not help you as the API expects a token, not username/password. you'd probably need a refresh token that does not expire and would allow your client to request a fresh access token each time it wants to access the API...

It all depends on the authentication mechanism used by your API...I'd first figure out if your API is indeed using OAuth2, and if so, learn about authentication flows (e.g. https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-oauth-2/) ...client credentials flow is probably what you'd want if the API allows for it...

*update*: Attempt 3 might be worth a try, i've never done it though. you might be able to send the credentials by submitting the corresponding form data via python requests...then that should in theory provide you with an authorization code which you can use to get a token...

Comment: Are you saying that even if I manage to add username/pass and click login, this will not be enough, as I also will be provided with a token, when I need to parse and carry with myself until the end of the auth?

Comment: yes...if oauth2 authentication is used, then the user would authenticate through the form. the auth server would check the credentials and in case of success redirect the user back to the client (your app) passing it an authorization code. the client would also need to authenticate itself (basic auth with cliient id + credentials) and provide the authorization code in order to obtain an access token....it is that access token you'd then send to the resource server (your api, e.g.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

Comment: also, your app/client would have to be registered with the auth server/service provider (to get a client id and client credentials).
this is however _if_ your api is using oauth2 (which I'm just guessing at this point)...should this be the case, I'd spend the $10 and invest 4h to follow the udemy course I linked. It helped me to understand the flow and gives concrete examples how to interact with some widely used apis, such as the one from facebook (and others)....its money and time well spent.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. I will sign up for it. On my end, it shows $59.99 thought :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for showing us your attempts.

If the attempt 2 returns 200 status code. It means it does work which means that `basic auth` works. Simple solution is to just pass `auth=(username, password)` to all of your api calls.

Or you can use `requests.Session()` to authenticate once and keep the session provided that server supports session authentication.

Hope this helps.

Comment: just guessing, but I suppose attempt 2 accesses the api and gets redirected to the authentication form...which is successfully requested via http...hence status code 200. it would also explain why basic authentication (against the actual api endpoint) fails despite sending username/password as you suggested.

Comment: Is documentation available for the api? Which can tell exactly which authentication protocol is in place.